# Lifetimes for String slices

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm going through the rust black book and it mentions lifetime elision rules, and how especially for functions inputting and returning &str (strings stored on the stack), don't need explicit lifetimes. My question is why did they do so in the first place. The way I've been visualizing a string in rust is somewhat like a slice that the variable now holds. Is that incorrect?

```
        let mut s = String::from("alfdj");
        let k = &s[0..1];
        let s = "laskjd";
        println!("{}",k);`
```

This is what I tried and what confused me about the relationship between the string s and the slice k. I redefine s and it has no effect on k which is why I thought the &str k became independent of the string s.

Comment: For what it's worth, `s` is `&'static str`, not `String`, when you redefine it. Are you trying to alter `s` instead of redefining?

Comment: Rust has the `String` "string buffer" type, which is heap-allocated. Then Rust has the `str` "string slice" type, which refers to an abstract string of known length. There is then the `&str` "string slice reference" type. `String` stores a `str` on the heap, and in your code, `&s[0..1]` results in getting an `&str` pointing into that heap string.

Comment: In your code, `let s = "laskjd";` is not assigning a new string, but creating a new variable `s` with the same name as the one declared before. But `k` still refers into the first `s`, you just can't access that variable by name anymore. This is called "shadowing".

Comment: If you remove the `let` from `let s = "laskjd";`, turning it into an assignment, you'll get a compiler error because the type of `"laskjd"` is `&'static str`, not `String`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a concept known as [variable shadowing](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/variable_bindings/scope.html). Whenever you define a variable using `let` or `let mut`, you are creating a new variable which happens to have the same variable name. The old variable still exists but cannot be accessed through its name. This is part of the notion of lexical scoping. Your code snippet is equivalent to the following:

```rust
let mut s = String::from("alfdj");
let k = &s[0..1];
let w = "laskjd";
println!("{}",k);
```

Here, we just replaced the second `s` with `w`.

The same thing happens when you call a function. For example, in the code

```rust
fn scoping() -> i32 {
   let x = 3;
   let g = |mut x| {
      x += 1;
      x
   };
   g(x) + x // evaluates to 7; calling g(x) doesn't change x
}
```

there are two different variables, both named `x`. Similarly, we can have the following occur:

```rust
let x = 3;
{
   let x = 4;
   println!("{}", x); // 4
   let x = "abc";
   println!("{}", x); // abc
}
println!("{}", x); // 3
```

Comment: Oh, this makes sense! I was thinking of it like changing the string. I didn't realize that the original string is still in the scope, only inaccessible.